# jQuery - ajax tabs and using cookies to remember active tab

Tags: jquery, cookies, tabs

I'm using jQuery to load content to a page via AJAX. I want to use cookies to remember which tab was last active, that way it will automatically load the proper page. My real question is how can I use the jQuery cookies plugin to remember the last active tab, then apply the class 'active' (which is how I'm displaying the content) to the same tab on reload or other visits?

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this will work (a bit abstract - since there are dozens of tabs and cookie plugins out there):

This code should trigger on tab click or hover - or whatever else event you use:

```
$.cookie('activeTab', 'activeTabId');//save current tab id in activeTab cookie
```

then to get back to that tab when user reenters the page(this code should go into your $(document).ready(), or whatever else method you use to determine that DOM is ready):

```
if($.cookie('activeTab')){//checking if cookie set
    $('#' . $.cookie('activeTab')).addClass('active');
}
```